# Mapbox GL approximate distance from bbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS to find out the nearest features to a clicked spot the user has clicked on the map. Its working great. But I'd like to output a approximate distance. The code Im using is below...

```
function nearestFeature(y,x) { 
    var bbox = [[y, x], [y, x]];
    var featuresBuilding = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, { layers: ['MyBuildingLayer'] });
    if (featuresBuilding[0]) {
        //found
    }else{
        //widen the area
        for (i = 1;i<100;i++) {
            bbox = [[y-i, x-i], [y+i, x+i]];
            featuresBuilding = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, { layers: ['MyBuildingLayer'] });
            if (featuresBuilding[0]) { 
                //calculate distance
                var distance = 100*i; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I might be complicating this issue but essentially I need to work out the distance a point difference is for the X / Y and multiply the meter distance to get a rough estimation. I used var distance = 100*i to illustrate this, I need to work out how to acertain the dummy 100 figure...

Comment: Is your goal to "stop" searching once you hit X amount of features?I think you need to clarify that a bit more.

Comment: Essentially I start widening the BBOX until I hit a specific building on a layer. Really this information is supplementary. What I need to find out is how to convert a point difference to a distance.

Comment: Still don't get whats the essence of your question. Maybe you can explain further what you're trying to achieve and where the problem lies. I can comprehend your code but I don't get: "work out the distance a point difference is for the X / Y".

Comment: My code uses a point or pixel I need to convert this into a distance. For example how far is 5px/points on my map i.e. 345 meters.

Comment: If you need to be moving between geographical and screen coordinates, why aren't you using `project` and `unproject`? https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#project

Comment: You want to know what the map coverage of 1 px would be as distance? Or do you want to calculate a distance between 2 points (then whats your 2nd point?)

Comment: Yes 1px as a distance if just what I need here

Comment: You should edit your question to clearify that. Currently it is really vague and as you see in the amount of comments people don't know what exactly you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had a project where I also needed the value of 1px as a distance value to build something like a scale control (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#scalecontrol)

The solution is using the bounding box of the current viewport to calculate the distance between 2 points. Dividing this by the users viewport width will give you the distance for 1 pixel. I Used the mapbox scale control to check my values against theirs and the result seems to be reasonable.

I came up with this solution (requires [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/)).
You can see the full working example on a quick jsfiddle I created: 
https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/38h7m5wx/

```js
function getDistance() {
  const bounds = map.getBounds();
  const topLeft = turf.point([bounds._ne.lng, bounds._ne.lat]);
  const topRight = turf.point([bounds._sw.lng, bounds._ne.lat]);
  const bottomLeft = turf.point([bounds._ne.lng, bounds._sw.lat]);
  const bottomRight = turf.point([bounds._sw.lng, bounds._sw.lat]);
  
  const middleLeft = turf.midpoint(topLeft, bottomLeft);
  const middleRight = turf.midpoint(topRight, bottomRight);
  const distance = turf.distance(middleLeft, middleRight, 'kilometers');
  return distance;
}

const clientWidth = window.innerWidth;
const distance = getDistance();
const onePixel = distance / clientWidth;
console.log(`1px is ~${onePixel.toFixed(3)} km or ${Math.ceil((onePixel) * 1000)} meters`);
```